How to create a curved function based on two intersected linear functions?
I want to create a function that looks like the red curve in the picture. How do I proceed?
Example

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

If you want a function $f(x)$ with a given value and slope at two distinct values of $x$, you can fit it to a cubic polynomial.  For example, if you want $f(-1) = -1$, $f'(-1) = 2$, $f(1) = 1$ and $f'(1) = 1/2$,
write $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$ and solve the equations
$$ \eqalign{a_0 - a_1 + a_2 - a_3 &= -1\cr
                  a_1 - 2 a_2 + 3 a_3 &= 2\cr
            a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + a_3 &= 1\cr
                  a_1 + 2 a_2 + 3 a_3 &= 1/2\cr} $$
to get $$ a_0 = \frac{3}{8},\ a_1 = \frac{7}{8},\ a_2 = -\frac{3}{8},\ a_3 = \frac{1}{8} $$

